# Scala: type mismatch; found : Unit required: Boolean

Tags: scala, syntax

Hi I'm just trying out my first bits of scala and have hit this error which I don't understand. I've been trying to work it out and have exhausted my ideas. Help?

```
scala> def calculate(count: Int) : Boolean =    
     |           if (count<0) false
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Boolean
                 if (count<0) false
                 ^
```

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have to have an `else` clause, otherwise the type checker doesn't know what the return type is when it's *not* the case that `count<0`.

```
def calculate(count: Int): Boolean =    
  if (count<0) false
  else true
```

Or, better yet, you don't need the if-statement at all:

```
def calculate(count: Int) = count >= 0
```

Comment: To be precise, the compiler _does_ know the return type. An `if` statement without `else` branch has result type `Unit` (and that's what the error says), so `if( count < 0 ) false` is short for `if( count < 0 ) false else ()`.