# found Unit: required Int. Why is the error not obvious?

Tags: scala

I have a method that is supposed to return an Int. I am trying to understand why Eclipse won't let me compile this, even though it looks apparent to me inside the if statement that I am indeed returning an Int. Is there something I am missing very obvious? I am trying to understand this aspect of Scala before proceeding to write more code.

Here is the method:

```
def contains1(sfType: TokenType): Int = {
     if (Tokens.KEYWORDS.contains(sfType)) {
      val retVal = TokenTypes.RESERVED_WORD
    }
  }
```

Eclipse complains on line 2 --- 'type mismatch; found : Unit required: Int"

```
TokenTypes is - public abstract interface org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.TokenTypes and RESERVED_WORD is - public static final int RESERVED_WORD = 6;
```

I have read this post here: [found: Unit required: Int - How to correct this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753542/found-unit-required-int-how-to-correct-this?rq=1) and tried to solve the problem before posting it, but I am still at a loss.

Edit: The method is supposed to return an Int and I had typed in the return type wrongly. My problem remains the same. Eclipse still complains.

Comment: What is line 2, what is KEYWORDS.

Comment: I am confused.  Are you saying that `contains1` should return an Int, or `Tokens.KEYWORDS.contains()`?

Comment: @sberry, contains1 should return an Int

Comment: @djechlin, KEYWWORDS is "final val RESERVED_WORD: Int" . This is a field in public final class TokenTypes

Comment: Since you are explicitly saying the contains1 returns Unit, there will be no return value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala: type mismatch; found : Unit required: Boolean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539777/scala-type-mismatch-found-unit-required-boolean)

Comment: Also, it's not quite a duplicate. Please don't vote to close. The other situation was also a 1 legged if, but it didn't try this "retVal" stuff.

Comment: 1. Assignment's type is Unit. You are assigning some value to `retVal`. You can check that in the repl:

scala> val test = {val retVal = 1}
test: Unit = ()

2. What would you expect the function to return in case your if statement does not hold? How would this function know that?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I'll first explain what type `Unit` is, just in case. Even if you know already, other people having the same kind of problem might well not know it.

Type `Unit` is similar to what is known in C or Java as `void`. In those languages, that means *"this does not return anything"*. However, *every method in Scala returns a value*.

To bridge the gap between every method returning something and not having anything useful to return, there's `Unit`. This type is an `AnyVal`, which means it isn't allocated on the heap, unless it gets boxed or is the type of a field on an object. Furthermore, it has only *one* value, whose literal is `()`. That is, you could write this:

```
val x: Unit = ()
```

The practical effect of this is that, when a method "returns" `Unit`, the compiler doesn't have to actually return any value, since it already knows what that value is. Therefore, it can implement methods returning `Unit` by declaring them, on the bytecode level, as being `void`.

Anyway, if you don't want to return anything, you return `Unit`.

Now let's look at the code given. Eclipse says it returns `Unit`, and, in fact, Eclipse is correct. However, most people would actually make the error of having that method return `AnyVal` or `Any`, not `Unit`. See the following snippet for an example:

```
scala> if (true) 2
res0: AnyVal = 2
```

So, what happened? Well, when Scala finds an `if` statement, it has to figure out what is the type returned by it (in Scala, `if` statements return values as well). Consider the following hypothetical line:

```
if (flag) x else y
```

Clearly, the returned value will be either `x` or `y`, so the type must be such that both `x` and `y` will fit. One such type is `Any`, since *everything* has type `Any`. If both `x` and `y` were of the same type -- say, `Int` -- then that would also be a valid return type. Since Scala picks the most specific type, it would pick `Int` over `Any`.

Now, what happens when you *don't* have an `else` statement? Even in the absence of an `else` statement, the condition may be false -- otherwise, there would be no point in using `if`. What Scala does, in this case, is to *add an `else` statement*. That is, it rewrites that `if` statement like this:

```
if (true) 2 else ()
```

Like I said before: if you do not have anything to return, return `Unit`! That is exactly what happens. Since both `Int` and `Unit` are `AnyVal`, and given that `AnyVal` is more specific than `Any`, that line returns `AnyVal`.

So far I have explained what others *might* have seen, but not what happens in that specific code in the question:

```
if (Tokens.KEYWORDS.contains(sfType)) {
  val retVal = TokenTypes.RESERVED_WORD
}
```

We have seen already that Scala will rewrite it like this:

```
if (Tokens.KEYWORDS.contains(sfType)) {
  val retVal = TokenTypes.RESERVED_WORD
} else ()
```

We have *also* seen that Scala will pick the most specific type between the two possible results. Finally, Eclipse tells use that the return type is `Unit`, so the only possible explanation is that the type of this:

```
  val retVal = TokenTypes.RESERVED_WORD
```

is also `Unit`. And that's precisely correct: statements that declare things in Scala have type `Unit`. And, so, by the way, do assignments.

The solution, as others have pointed out, is to remove the assignment and add an `else` statement also returning an `Int`:

```
def contains1(sfType: TokenType): Int =
  if (Tokens.KEYWORDS.contains(sfType)) TokenTypes.RESERVED_WORD
  else -1
```

(note: I have reformatted the method to follow the coding style more common among Scala programmers)

Comment: Great answer, especially the first bit about AnyVal.

Comment: Great answer.  I wish I could transport the checkmark to this much better answer.

Comment: Painstakingly and meticulous. Great answer. Sorry about the late replies, Daniel.

Comment: Well explained answer

Comment: @Daniel C. Sobral Thank you so much ...excellent  can you help me with below   trait Processor00 {
  def process(x:String): Unit
}
case class Processor20() extends Processor0 {
   override def process(x:String): Unit = println("Processor20 x :" + x)
}
case class Processor30() extends Processor0 {
   override def process(x:String): Unit = println("Processor30 x :" + x)
}

Comment: object UnitTest1 {
  def main( args : Array[String]):Unit ={
    val s:String = "yes"
    val myFuncs: Map[String,(String) => Unit ]=  Map(  
           "string2" -> Processor20().process(s), //Eroor 1. type mismatch; found : Unit required: String ⇒ Unit
          "string3" -> Processor30().process(s)
        )
   myFuncs.values.foreach(v => v());//how to call all  Objects' i.e.  process("Hi") here ???
  }
}

Comment: @Daniel C. Sobral sir can you please help me with this    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53004737/how-to-call-this-objects-methods-in-a-map

Answer (score 10):

In scala there's no single `if` statement

Since each expression when evaluated must return a value (it can be an empty value, of type `Unit`), the `if` expression must be always matched with an `else` branch, and both must return the same type, or in the worst case scala will infer the most common supertype.

In your code you return a `Int` from the `if` branch, but the `else` branch is missing.

#### updated

As stated correctly in other answers:

the single `if` expression returns the only alternative within it, which for the original post is the return value of an assignment, which is `()` of type `Unit`

Comment: Note, too, that the overt true branch of the expression in the original question is also of type Unit, since it is a val definition, not a simple expression.

Lastly, and this is a pet peeve of mine an entirely aside from the point of the question, all of the braces in the original are redundant and in my book should be removed.

Answer (score 10):

I have a feeling you need to change your method to look like one of the following

```
def contains1(sfType: TokeType): Int = {
  if (Tokens.KEYWORDS.contains(sfType))
    TokenTypes.RESERVED_WORD
  else 
    -1
}

def contains1(sfType: TokenType) = if (Tokens.KEYWORDS.contains(sfType)) TokenTypes.RESERVED_WORD else -1
```

Comment: My apologies. The method contains1 is supposed to return an Int, and my method seems to be returning an Int, but Eclipse still complains.

Comment: @ilango: you should change the accepted answer to Daniel's instead of mine.  While the code I provided does work, his answer is far superior as to explaining **why** my code works.

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse thinks that if the "if" block is false, i.e, `Tokens.KEYWORDS.contains(sfType)` is `false`, then the return type will indeed be `Unit`, which is the problem.

Comment: Thanks, Bob. You have added more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Scala 3. When I used the "quiet syntax" without braces and my functions were out of alignment. So, the definition of the second function I had, ended up in the definition of the first function above it...